# How can I evaluate string as a code in PHP?

Tags: php, string, if-statement, eval

I have a loop which returns the string below.

```
if(in_array(Metformin (Glucophage), $arr) || in_array('Test String'), $arr)) {This is a content for Metformin}
```

How can I use it as a code in PHP?

Comment: Eval maybe what you are looking for. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: if `eval()` is the answer, its often a sign your doing something wrong, why are generating a code sting in the first place? There is bound to be a better way

Comment: Can you describe what you are attempting to achieve with this code?

Comment: Why do you have a loop that generates a string of php code? Why not run the PHP code in the loop.